# CSS: How to add smooth shift to div width upon text change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, transition

If anyone can phrase this question better than I can, please advise and I will alter (or edit yourself).

Here's my current jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5v7mzadu/

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="text-cycler">
    WE <div class="c-text" id="ctext-1">CARE</div>
       <div class="c-text" id="ctext-2">THINK</div>
       <div class="c-text" id="ctext-3">SEE</div>
       <div class="c-text" id="ctext-1">KNOW</div>
</div>
```

**My CSS:**

```
.text-cycler {
     text-align:center;
     font-size:25px;
}
.c-text {
    display:inline-block
}
```

**My Javascript:**

```
var divs = $('div[id^="ctext-"]').hide(),
           i = 0;

(function cycle() { 

    divs.eq(i).fadeIn(400)
        .delay(1000)
        .fadeOut(400, cycle);

    i = ++i % divs.length;

})();
```

As you can see the second word fades in/out,. I'd like to add a smooth transition to the div, so that the width of the div container does NOT abruptly change width size. (so that the width "snap" is more smooth)

Can anyone help?

Comment: It is because you are using `text-align:center;`. So the view will adjust based on the length of the text. By using `text-align:left;` you can solve this. Check whether it is ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you needed the animation over the content and text alignment center.
And indeed this must solve your purpose.

I have added `span{white-space: nowrap; vertical-align: text-top;}` to force it to align in single line, and added jQuery animate method to animate the width of the rotating text

And here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wakqp2ro/) for you to play around

```js
var divs = $('div[id^="ctext-"]').hide(),
  i = 0;

(function cycle() {
  divs.eq(i)
    .animate(400, function() {

      $('.x').animate({
        width: $(this).innerWidth()
      });
    })
    .fadeIn(400)
    .delay(1000)
    .fadeOut(400, cycle);
  i = ++i % divs.length;
})();
```

```css
.text-cycler {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}

span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}

.c-text {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-cycler">
  <span> WE </span>
  <span class="x">
    <div class="c-text" id="ctext-1">CARE</div>
    <div class="c-text" id="ctext-2">THINK</div>
    <div class="c-text" id="ctext-3">SEE</div>
    <div class="c-text" id="ctext-1">KNOW</div>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is almost perfect. One question though, when it switches from a shorter word, to a longer word, how do you make the visibility of the entire word possible. For example, when it switches from "Care" to "Think", the letters "nk" are briefly cutoff and unseen. Anyway to fix this issue?

Comment: Yes you can fix it by speeding up the animate method like `$('.x').animate({width: $(this).innerWidth()},100);` That will fix the issue, but speed up the transition as well

Comment: Thanks! Very useful addition.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I need. I've got only one problem, on this line:
`.animate(400, function(){` I cannot pass 400 here because I receive an IDE error `No overload matches this call.`. Without this, text `WE` is not animating (translating on x-axis). Could you tell me what should be changed here (I guess on latest jQuery version)?

Answer (score 0):

See this snippet

```js
var divs = $('div[id^="ctext-"]').hide(),
    i = 0;

(function cycle() { 

  divs.eq(i).fadeIn(400)
    .delay(1000)
    .fadeOut(400, cycle);

  i = ++i % divs.length;

})();
```

```css
.text-cycler {
  font-size:25px;
  position:fixed; /*added*/
  padding-left:40% /*added*/
}

.c-text {
  display:inline-block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-cycler" align="center">
WE <div class="c-text" id="ctext-1">CARE</div><div class="c-text" id="ctext-2">THINK</div><div class="c-text" id="ctext-3">SEE</div><div class="c-text" id="ctext-1">KNOW</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**JavascriptLess way.**

If you want to get funky. (No seriously, this is more a funky solution than usable)

```css
.text-cycler {
  width:75%;
  margin:auto;
  user-select: none;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:5vw;
}
.text-cycler:after {
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
  animation: change;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes change {
  0% {
    content: "CARE";
    opacity: 0;
  }
  3% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  22% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    content: "CARE";
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25.1% {
    content: "THINK";
  }
  28% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  47% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    content: "THINK";
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50.1% {
    content: "SEE";
  }
  53% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  72% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75% {
    content: "SEE";
    opacity: 0;
  }
  75.1% {
    content: "KNOW";
  }
  78% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  97% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    content: "KNOW";
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="text-cycler">
  WE
</div>
```

Comment: Why? Because i am a bit nuts.